# d3 - unable to add select/option drop down to svg-g element

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, html-select

I am intending to add a circle pack, radio and drop down menu to a SVG and toggle between these (on the same svg).

I wasn't able to add the select/option dropdown menu to the SVG that is created with width/height of 600/600. In the element console, I am able to see the `g`-element and the drop down select option.
But on the screen, the `g#menu` has a 0x0 size? Why is this so? Any pointers/inputs?

NOTE: Here I am trying to add the dropdown menu dynamically using D3.js instead of hardcoding a selectio/option or div in the body element. I do this to enable toggling between different views.

```
var svg1 = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 600)
            .attr("height", 600)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", 
              "translate(0,0)"));  
var buttonNames = ["button 1", "button 2", "button 3", "button 4"];
var menug = svg1.append("g")
                .attr("id","menug")
                .attr("transform","translate(60,60)");

var menu = d3.select("#menug")
             .append("select")
             .attr("id", "menu");                    


menu.selectAll("option")
        .data(buttonNames)
    .enter().append("option")
        .text(function(d){return d;});
```

Comment: I wrote an answer but I deleted it because I'm confused: in your text, you say you're appending the select to the SVG, but in your code you're appending it to the body. Which one is correct?

Comment: Also, in your question you refer to `g#menu`, although, in your snippet, the id `menu` is assigned to the `select`. Something is wrong here.

Comment: OK, @gayathri, I undeleted my answer. If you are appending it to the SVG, have a look. If you are appending it to the body, ignore my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

```js
var buttonNames = ["button 1", "button 2", "button 3", "button 4"];
var l=4;
for(i=0;i<buttonNames.length;i++){if(l<buttonNames[i].length)l=buttonNames[i].length};
var width = 400, height = 300;
l=l*10;
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("class","dropdown");
select = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class","select");
select.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
 .attr("y",  10 )
 .attr("width", l)
 .attr("height", 30);
select.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
 .attr("y",30 )
  .attr("id","mydropdown")
 .text( buttonNames[0]);
  
var options = svg.selectAll(".myBars")
 .data(buttonNames)
 .enter()
 .append("g");
 
options.attr("class", "option").on("click", function() { document.getElementById("mydropdown").innerHTML=this.getElementsByTagName("text")[0].innerHTML;
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
});
options.append("rect").attr("x", 10)
 .attr("y", function(d,i){ return 40 + i*30})
 .attr("width", l)
 .attr("height", 30);

 options.append("text").attr("x", function(d){ return 15})
 .attr("y", function(d,i){ return 60 + i*30})
 .text(function(d){ return d});
```

```css
rect {
 fill: teal;
}
.dropdown .option {
  display:none;
}
.dropdown rect{
  stroke-width:0.5;
  stroke:rgb(0,0,0)
}
.dropdown:hover .option {
  display:unset;
}
.dropdown {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.A. Shall try it...so we construct the select/option dropdown as rectangles and add them to the SVG.. I have altered my code to use select/option HTML elements and used opacity and z-index for layering with the SVG

Comment: Just tried it works! The one advantage of using svgs even for these customised drop down (instead of good old HTML elements), is the g-element. Grouping using 'g' will make it easier to toggle between views of different 'g's on same SVG. will try this, dont know if i am absolutely correct

Answer (score 4):

This question is so common that I created this example in the documentation. The example deals with SVG elements incorrectly appended to an SVG, but the same reasoning applies to HTML elements being appended to an SVG: you have to know what elements can have children and *what* kind of children they can have. More details at the bottom of this post.

In a nutshell: you *cannot* append any HTML element to an SVG (unless using foreignObject). The element will show up in the console, but won't work.

Note: I'm answering your written question and ignoring your code because, funny enough, in your code, you are correctly appending the HTML element to the `body`.

---

**Correctly appending an SVG element**

This is a relatively common mistake: You created an `rect` element, in a bar chart for instance, and you want to add a text label (let's say, the value of that bar). So, using the same variable that you used to append the `rect` and define its `x` and `y` position, you append your `text` element. Very logic, you may think. But this will not work.

**How does this mistake occur?**

Let's see a concrete example, a very basic code for creating a bar chart ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/zch1g4tm/)):

```
var data = [210, 36, 322, 59, 123, 350, 290];

var width = 400, height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var bars = svg.selectAll(".myBars")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect");

bars.attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", function(d,i){ return 10 + i*40})
    .attr("width", function(d){ return d})
    .attr("height", 30);
```

Which gives us this result:

[image]

But you want to add some text elements, maybe a simple value to each bar. So, you do this:

```
bars.append("text")
   .attr("x", 10)
   .attr("y", function(d,i){ return 10 + i*40})
   .text(function(d){ return d});
```

And, voilà: nothing happens! If you doubt it, [here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/zch1g4tm/1/).

**"But I'm seeing the tag!"**

If you inspect the SVG created by this last code, you're gonna see this:

[image]

And at this point a lot of people say: "But I'm seeing the text tag, it's appended!". Yes, it is, but this doesn't mean it will work. You can append *anything*! See this, for example:

```
svg.append("crazyTag");
```

It will give you this result:

```
<svg>
    <crazyTag></crazyTag>
</svg>
```

But you don't expect any result just because the tag is there, do you?

**Append SVG elements the correct way**

Learn what SVG elements can hold children, reading the [specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html). In our last example, the code doesn't work because `rect` elements cannot contain `text` elements. So, how to display our texts?

Create another variable, and append the `text` to the SVG:

```
var texts = svg.selectAll(".myTexts")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text");

texts.attr("x", function(d){ return d + 16})
    .attr("y", function(d,i){ return 30 + i*40})
    .text(function(d){ return d});
```

And this is the outcome:

[image]

And [here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/zch1g4tm/2/).

Comment: thanks @Gerado. Sorry abt the mistake in the code. I was really trying to add the drop down to the svg and not the body (yeah, adding it to body is straight fwd and would work). So this is really useful, not all HTML elements cannot be added as children to SVGs.....and if I insist , need to use foreign objects else needs to design  the foreign objects using svgs itself...

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that foreignObject doesn't work in Internet Explorer... Just append the select to the HTML, not to the SVG, and you're safe.

Comment: k @Gerardo. Have added them as HTML elements with zindex and opacity for layering with SVG